# Awesomium. How to work in parallel with two WebViews through proxy?

Tags: c#, webview, proxy, awesomium

I'm working with Awesomium .Net 1.7.5.1 and i have a problem. When i'm creating two (or more) WebViews with not default proxy parameters i can't load pages into them at same time. When i'm trying to do this - only one WebView loads its page correctly when others are "die": they are not firing events, not finishing load etc.
This code can repeat the problem:

```
private static void Main()
    {
        var isWebCoreRunning = false;
        var webCoreThread = new Thread(() =>
                           {
                             WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig());
                             WebCore.Run((sender, args) => isWebCoreRunning = true);
                           }) {Name = "WebCore Thread", IsBackground = true};

        webCoreThread.Start();
        while (!isWebCoreRunning)
            Task.Delay(10).Wait();

        var proxyConfig = String.Format("{0}:{1}", "proxyHost", proxyPort);
        var webView1 = WebCore.DoWork(() =>
                 {
                   var webPreferences = new WebPreferences { ProxyConfig = proxyConfig };
                   var webSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(webPreferences);
                   return WebCore.CreateWebView(100, 100, webSession);
                 });
        var webView2 = WebCore.DoWork(() =>
                 {
                   var webPreferences = new WebPreferences { ProxyConfig = proxyConfig };
                   var webSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(webPreferences);
                   return WebCore.CreateWebView(100, 100, webSession);
                 });

        webView1.LoginRequest += OnLoginRequest;
        webView2.LoginRequest += OnLoginRequest;

        webView1.LoadingFrameComplete += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("X");
        webView2.LoadingFrameComplete += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("X");

        WebCore.QueueWork(() => webView1.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.ru/"));
        WebCore.QueueWork(() => webView2.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.ru/"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnLoginRequest(object sender, LoginRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Username = "proxyLogin";
        e.Password = "proxyPassword";
        e.Handled = EventHandling.Modal;
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
```

Here we will get only one "X" in console. All works fine when i'm not using proxy. Can someone point me what is the problem? Is it a bug (but it's strange how it can't be still unknown) or i missed something?

Comment: I have the same situation. Seems like a bug and it is very dissapointing.